# Jest 'it' block fails only when placed after empty 'it' block

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My 'it' block will fail, but only if it is placed after a previous 'it' block. the previous block is empty. If it is placed before, it passes.

```
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //do some stuff...
  })
  it('it-1', () => {
    //passes, empty
  }) 
  it('it-2', () => {
    //fails
  }) 
})

describe('test2', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //do some stuff...
  })
  it('it-2', () => {
    //passes
  }) 
  it('it-1', () => {
    //passes, empty
  }) 
})
```

any ideas what could be going on? i couldn't paste the actual code for privacy reasons, sorry about that. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I've figured out that it has something to do with jest.resetAllMocks() being called in the root afterEach(). But i'm not sure how to fix it without removing resetAllMocks

Answer (score 0):

well the fix was putting a 'spy.mockRestore()' at the end of each 'it' block, although I couldn't tell you why that fixes it.